# Git: how to separate out a feature branch after the fact

Tags: git, feature-branch

How can I move some commits of a feature from an existing branch into a feature branch, and effectively remove them from the current branch - as if the feature was developed in a separate feature branch?

Background: the branch `develop` contains commits to two features A (say, 50 commits) and B (10 commits) wildly mixed, since they originally should have been in the same release. Now we are delaying feature B. Thus, we want to have only feature A in the `develop` branch, and a new `featureB` branch that contains the commits of A or A and B, such that if we merge both branches, we get the current position of the `develop` branch.

One way to do that would be to create the `featureB` branch from the current position of the `develop` branch and then reversely apply the commits from A to `develop`. But then the merge of the new `develop` and `featureB` would just be A.

Another way would be to rename the current `develop` into `featureB` and cherry pick all commits of A into a new `develop` branch. But that would effectively modify the history of `develop`, which is troublesome.

What is a better way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

If your `develop` branch has been published and you don't want to rewrite its history (which would be the easiest way), then you could indeed revert your changes in `develop`, start a new `featureB` branch off rebased `B` changes on top of `develop`. Something along the line:

```
 #given history (top - newest)
 #shaA3 <-- develop, HEAD
 #shaB2
 #shaA2
 #shaB1
 #shaA1
```

revert:

```
 git revert B2
 git revert B1
```

now the history contains:

```
 #revert of shaB1 <-- develop, HEAD
 #revert of shaB2
 #shaA3
 #shaB2
 #shaA2
 #shaB1
 #shaA1
```

create `featureB` and re-play reverted commits anew:

```
 git checkout -b featureB
 git rebase -i --onto develop shaB1~1 featureB
```

Comment out all the commits except for those belonging to feature B (`shaB1` and `shaB2` in our case) and complete the rebase. At this point you should have the history:

```
 #shaB2' <-- featureB, HEAD
 #shaB1'
 #revert of shaB1 <-- develop
 #revert of shaB2
 #shaA3
 #shaB2
 #shaA2
 #shaB1
 #shaA1
```

To double-check that everything went well, you can do `git diff shaA3` - should be empty, `git diff develop` - should contain all of the desired B changes.

P.S. You can of course use cherry-pick or revert of reverts to replay the b changes into `branchB`, instead of the rebase interactive, e.g. when staying on develop:

```
 git checkout -b branchB
 git revert <revert of shaB1>
 git revert <revert of shaB2>
```

Will give you:

```
 #revert of revert of shaB2 = shaB2' <-- featureB, HEAD
 #revert of revert of shaB1 = shaB1'
 #revert of shaB1 <-- develop
 #revert of shaB2
 #shaA3
 #shaB2
 #shaA2
 #shaB1
 #shaA1
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice detailed answer! It seems you can also go without the double reversion - see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29628784/21499 , though. I suppose that looks nicer in the history.

Answer (score 2):

By far the cleanest method if you can manage it at all is to just write the correct histories and switch refs. Calling the base of the history you want to split `X`,

```
git checkout -b new-develop X
git cherry-pick [all the feature_A commits]
# repeat the cherry-pick as needed or convenient if there's too many 
git checkout -b new-featureB X
git cherry-pick [all the feature_B commits]
# ...
```

then swap names around with `git branch -m`, force-push, and have everyone refetch and rebase any unpublished work as necessary.

Every other option is going to leave you with a really messy history, and there's no reason to inflict that on all of posterity if it's at all reasonable to avoid it.  *Do* avoid it if for any reason communication is a problem.

If you really can't do that, then see [@MykolaGurov's nicely detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29356354/1290731).

---

( `branch` → `checkout -b` . . . )

Answer (score 0):

Create branch `featureB` from current state of develop. Commit code to branch `develop` for any further development of featureA. Commit code to branch `featureB` for development of featureB. Regularly rebase branch `featureB` against branch `develop` so that it has the changes which are being added for development of featureA.

Comment: Thanks, but that applies only to future commits. The problem is that I have to remove or revert the already existing commits of featureB from branch develop, while having both branches mergeable into the current state. My question is how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid modifying the published history of branch `develop`, as in [@thill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29358212/21499), and also want to avoid reverting the reverted commits, as in [@Mykola Gorov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29356354/21499), you can also

1. Create branch `featureB` from `develop`
2. Revert the commits of feature `B` into branch `develop`. It might be sensible to do this in a single commit `revert B`, since this is one operation in the history.
3. Merge branch `develop` into `featureB` with strategy `ours`. This does not change any files in branch `featureB`, but marks the reverted commit from 2. as already merged into `featureB`. Thus, if you later merge the feature branch `featureB` back into `develop`, the result will *not* contain commit `revert B` anymore.

When merging `featureB` back into `develop` you might want to have `featureB` as the first parent of the commit. (E.g. you merge `develop` into `featureB` and then set `develop` to `featureB`, not the other way around.) I suppose that way the reversion won't confuse blame etc. anymore. (?)