# Create a branch from master with removed code

Tags: git, merge, branch

I wrote some code to implement two new features on a project, but I committed the changes to master. I now realize that this was a mistake, because one of the features is working well, and the other is not.

I would like to keep the working feature code in master, but remove the non-working feature code from master.

I'd like to have the current version of the project (with both features) in a new branch.

I would just create a new branch from master and then remove the code from the non-working feature from master, but I'm worried that the commits will basically be in the wrong order, and when I merge the branch back into master at some point, git will just discard the code for the non-working feature because the new branch will have been behind commits that remove that code.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/29350859/243861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should save your current master branch as a development branch, using

```
git checkout -b development
```

Next, you need to restore your master (because master is not for development, consider it sacrosanct unless you are the sole developer and you know what you are doing).

```
git branch -D master && git checkout -b master --track origin/master
```

If you don't have an upstream origin repository (github/bitbucket/gitlab etc), you can use `git reset HEAD` instead, or you can use `git checkout -b master <SHA_of_last_sane_commit_on_master>`.

Now, create a fresh branch for feature 1 out of master, and cherry pick commits for feature 1 to this branch, using

```
git checkout -b feature_1
git cherry-pick SHA_of_first_commit_for_feature_1
git cherry-pick SHA_of_second_commit_for_feature_1
# and so on.
```

Next, create a fresh branch for feature 2 in the same manner as above.

This assumes that your commits do not overlap for the 2 features, if they do, you will have to manually change contents of the files.

Now, when merging, all you need to do is merge `feature_1` into `master`, then `feature_2` into `master`.

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that my commits do overlap. I'll try to do things manually. Thanks for the advice for the future though.